# Passing data from a Service

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an Android service which collects data from some external hardware. I am making that data available to my Activities using a callback structure shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16651540/creating-a-callback-handler-to-handle-multiple-callbacks-in-android).

The data I'm making available is an `ArrayList<MyClass>`. While reading the Android API docs, it seems that a suggested way is to use broadcast events and `Parcelable`. I've also seen callbacks used in Android apps, so the question is what's the advantage of refactoring my code to use broadcasts?

Now, in the future, I am looking to allow external apps to access this service (Tasker, for example), so I'm guessing that the callback method I use will be for use in the local app only. So the question is how to do a callback from a `Service` to an `Activity` using an AIDL description.

Answer (score 1):

The way to allow a service to callback into an Activity is to have the service aidl interface define a registration function that takes another aidl interface as a parameter.

ServiceAidlInterface.aidl:

```
package com.test;

import com.test.CallbackAidlInterface;

interface ServiceAidlInterface {
    void registerCallback(in CallbackAidlInterface callback);
}
```

CallbackAidlInterface.aidl:

```
package com.test;

interface CallbackAidlInterface {
    void doCallback();
}
```

In your activity you need to define the following:

```
ServiceAidlInterface mService = null;

private CallbackAidlInterface mCallback = new CallbackAidlInterface.Stub() {
    @Override
    public void doCallback() throws RemoteException {
    }
};
```

So when the activity binds your onServiceConnected() gets called you can do the following:

```
   mService = ServiceAidlInterface.Stub.asInterface(serviceBinder);
   service.registerCallback(mCallback)
```